# How to create table in access that is only visible in the query tools of a report?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to mimic an odd table titled "BinCalcInfo" that I have found in a MS-Access that appears to only be located in the relationships of the query tools of a report. I would like to duplicate this table in another database.

So when I first encountered this table I tried to look in the "All Access Objects" under tables. I assumed that all tables in the database would be enumerated here. However it is not. The only place to find the table is by opening the report into design view, navigating to the "query tools" where it shows the source of all of the relationships and source of all of the fields on the report.

In the graphic area where it shows all of the tables and queries being utilized there is an extra table/query (not positive which) that does not appear anywhere on the list of tables or queries possible to add.

I suspect that there is a way to create a temporary table for a specific report, I just have no idea how to implement it or what to search to find direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is whether or not the table/query has merely been hidden from the Navigation Pane. To do this, ensure that **Show Hidden Objects** is enabled within the **Navigation Options**:

[image]

Assuming that you're **not** referring to a table/query which has been set to be Hidden, the query is likely to be a subquery defined only within the SQL of the query and not saved as a separate query in your database.

For example, if you were to copy the following SQL into the SQL View for a new query, you would see a subquery called `MySubQuery` shown in the graphical Design View, but **not** represented by a corresponding saved query in the database.

```sql
select * from (select count(*) as MyCount from msysobjects) as MySubQuery
```

As such, if you needed to determine how your 'hidden' query is defined so that you may reproduce it, you should inspect the SQL for your query.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was frustrating to see the table, but not be able to find it anywhere. I was able to locate it as soon as I selected the "Show Hidden Objects".